# How do I print a dictionary from json?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am running the code in this link as is.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-parse-data-from-json-into-python

```
import  json
f=open("c://mypython//my_file.txt", "r")
json_data= f.read()
parsed_json = (json.loads(json_data))

loaded_json = json.loads(json_data)
for x in loaded_json:
    print("%s: %d" % (x, loaded_json[x]))
```

When I run the code I get the error below. What is wrong here?

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict.

Comment: There is no way we can answer this question without knowing the contents of my_file.txt

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: That link has bad code. `for x in loaded_json: loaded_json[x]` will not work in general; it will only work if `loaded_json` is a dictionary and not an array, and the example it gives on the page is an array, so it won't actually work. Simply `print(x)` and don't try and print `loaded_json[x]` if you're using the example json on that page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this:

```
loaded_json[x]
```

because x is not an integer nor a slice but a dict. You must provide a number instead!